# How to implement js stroke code instead of CSS stroke

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I"m trying to achieve text stroke for my MeMe Making website. For English font is fine but not good result for non english because css outline stroke are going inside of the text not from outside.

After testing many css tricks, I realized that css cannot achieve my required stroke text. I've be working for many hours and still cannot success what I want to get.

Following is my website code with css stroke & I want to implement code look like this stroke text. http://jsfiddle.net/vNWn6/

[Current happening with css stroke Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSDUV.jpg)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // canvas related variables
    canvas = document.getElementById("mm-canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    imageObj = new Image();
    maxFontSize = 60;

    MAX_WIDTH = $('#meme-canvas').innerWidth()-20;
    MAX_HEIGHT = MAX_WIDTH;

    imageObj.onload = function(){
        width = imageObj.width;
        height = imageObj.height;

        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        draw();
    };
    imageObj.src = $(canvas).data('image');

    $(document).on('keyup', '.mm-text', function(){
        draw();
    });

    $('#add-textbox').click(function(){
        var that = $(this);
        var makeid = makeId();
        that.parent().before('<div class="form-group mb-form-group"><input type="text" data-position="'+makeid+'" name="title" placeholder="More Text" class="form-control mm-text pull-left"><div class="mm-spectrum pull-right"><input type="text" value="#fff" class="font" class="form-control"><input type="text" value="#000" class="stroke" class="form-control"></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div>');
        $('.resizable:last-child').before('<div id="'+makeid+'" style="position:absolute; top:'+((canvas.height/2)-50)+'px; width:100%; height:100px; opacity:0.4" class="resizable"></div>');

        $('input[data-position="'+makeid+'"]').next().find('.font').spectrum({
            clickoutFiresChange: true,
        });
        $('input[data-position="'+makeid+'"]').next().find('.stroke').spectrum({
            clickoutFiresChange: true,
        });

        $("#"+makeid).resizable({
          containment: ".mm-contain",
          stop: function(){ draw(); }
        }).draggable({
            containment: '.mm-contain',
            stop: function(){ draw(); }
        });

    });

    $('.mm-contain').hover(function(){
        $('.resizable').toggleClass('ui-state-active');
    });

    $( ".resizable" ).resizable({
      containment: ".mm-contain",
      stop: function(){ draw(); }
    }).draggable({
        containment: '.mm-contain',
        stop: function(){ draw(); }
    });
    $(".font").spectrum({
        clickoutFiresChange: true,
    });
    $(".stroke").spectrum({
        clickoutFiresChange: true,
    });

    $(document).on('change', '.font, .stroke', draw);

});
function makeId(){
    var text = "";
    var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

// clear the canvas & redraw all texts
function draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, width, height);

    $('.mm-text').each(function(index){
        var that = $(this);
        var text = that.val().trim();

        var dataPos = that.attr('data-position');

        var textboxWidth = $('#'+dataPos).innerWidth();
        that.attr('data-fontsize', maxFontSize);
        var textFont = that.attr('data-fontsize');

        ctx.font= textFont+"px impact";

        var linest = fragmentText(text, textboxWidth-textFont);

        if(linest.length == 1){
            //maxFontSize = 60;
            that.attr('data-fontsize', maxFontSize);
        }
        if(linest.length == 2){
            //maxFontSize = 50;
            that.attr('data-fontsize', 50);
        }
        if(linest.length == 3){
            //maxFontSize = 40;
            that.attr('data-fontsize', 40);
        }
        if(linest.length >= 4){
            //maxFontSize = 30;
            that.attr('data-fontsize', 30);
        }
        textFont = that.attr('data-fontsize');
        ctx.font= textFont+"px impact";
        ctx.fillStyle = that.next().find('.font').val()
        ctx.shadowColor = that.next().find('.stroke').val();
        ctx.strokeStyle = that.next().find('.stroke').val();

        var lines = fragmentText(text, textboxWidth-textFont);
        $('#'+dataPos).css('height', parseInt(lines.length*textFont)+'px');
        lines.forEach(function(line, i) {
            ctx.fillText(line.toUpperCase(), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().left + (textboxWidth/2)), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().top + (i + 1) * textFont));
            ctx.strokeText(line.toUpperCase(), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().left + (textboxWidth/2)), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().top + (i + 1) * textFont));
        });
    });
}

function fragmentText(text, maxWidth) {
    var words = text.toString().split(' '),
        lines = [],
        line = "";
    if (ctx.measureText(text).width < maxWidth) {
        return [text];
    }
    while (words.length > 0) {
        while (ctx.measureText(words[0]).width >= maxWidth) {
            var tmp = words[0];
            words[0] = tmp.slice(0, -1);
            if (words.length > 1) {
                words[1] = tmp.slice(-1) + words[1];
            } else {
                words.push(tmp.slice(-1));
            }
        }
        if (ctx.measureText(line + words[0]).width < maxWidth) {
            line += words.shift() + " ";
        } else {
            lines.push(line);
            line = "";
        }
        if (words.length === 0) {
            lines.push(line);
        }
    }
    return lines;
}

function saveCanvas()
{
    temp_width = MAX_WIDTH;
    temp_height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    MAX_WIDTH = 500;
    MAX_HEIGHT = MAX_WIDTH;
    draw();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mm-canvas");
    ctx.font = '12px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    ctx.shadowColor = '#000';
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText(waterMarkText, 3, canvas.height - 3);
    var theimage=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    MAX_WIDTH = temp_width;
    MAX_HEIGHT = temp_height;
    draw();
    $.post(rootURL+'/canvas',
        { image: theimage, _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
        function(data){
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data.status == 'success')
            {
                window.location.href = rootURL+'/canvas?id='+data.slug;
            }
        }
    );
}

function publishCanvas()
{
    MAX_WIDTH = 500;
    MAX_HEIGHT = MAX_WIDTH;
    draw();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mm-canvas");
    var theimage=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var ctitle = '';

    var form = $('<form action="'+rootURL+'/create?publish=yes" method="post">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="canvas" value="'+theimage+'" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="ctitle" value="'+ctitle+'" />' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'+$('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')+'" />' +
    '</form>');
    $('body').append(form);
    $(form).submit();
}
```

Comment: Finally, at least I found the problem, following code line.. stroke layer is overlapping over main font and get ugly result. Is someone know how could I put back the stroke layer to behind of the text? 

    ctx.strokeText(line.toUpperCase(), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().left + (textboxWidth/2)), parseInt($('#'+dataPos).position().top + (i + 1) * textFont));